# camera.inoがinsert SD!になってしまう。

Tags: spresense

Arduino IDE 1.8.9 + Spresense（1.4)の環境で、
SDHCI >>> read_write.inoは、SDに正常に書き込みできるのに、
Camera >>> camera.inoは、"Insert SD card!" になる。
board_sdcard_enable: ERROR: Failed to mount the SDCARD. 5
上のエラーは何を示していますか？

Answer (score 0):

SDカードの接触不良でした。カード面を布で擦って何度かやり直してみたら動きました。